# Why is JGit's add command very slow?

Tags: git, jgit

I have a code base counting about 2000 files. Working with `JGit 4.3.1.201605051710-r` on `OS X El Captain 10.11`.

Calling `jgit init` takes almost no time.

Calling `jgit add .` takes about `3sec`. Even when calling it repeatedly, it takes `2.7sec`.

Using `git v2.8.2`, it takes `2sec` complete the `git add .` operation. However, subsequent calls take only `0.015sec`.

Why is `JGit` so much slower? Even when the working copy is clean, the `jgit add .` command still runs for `3sec` whilst `git` only for `0.015sec`.

This huge slowness prevents me using JGit in my application where I need to run `git add .` and then `git commit` commands many times.

Comment: It's a known bug, see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=494323

Comment: @Islah I know, I have reported the bug myself after not getting any response on this question :)

Comment: Haha, funny enough. I was stumbling across the same problem, then first to this question and second to your bug ticket. I'm glad you've already reported and discussed the issue on the eclipse bug tracker. Thank you!

Comment: @Islah Glad I could help. At least there is s workaround. But even after these years the bug still refuses to leave the JGit :(